# Fisher information $I(\theta,X)$,where X=(Y,Z)

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, fisher-information

Let $Y$ be the number of patients (out of n) who survive for one year after an operation. Let $Z$ be the number of patients who survive for 5 years. Let $\theta=(p,q)$ and suppose that we model $Y\sim Bin(n,p)$ and $Z|Y=y \sim Bin(y,q)$.

Let $X=(Y,Z)$, find the fisher information $I(\theta,X)$

I think the first step should be to derive the distribution of $X$?
Can someone help me with this step?

Comment: How does $\theta$ vary while it doesn,t seem to be a random variable

Comment: I think $\theta$ is the 2D parameter to be found, consisting of p and q?

Comment: $Z$ can be written as well as $Z\sim Bin(n,pq)$

Comment: But you already have the joint distribution of $(Y,Z),$ and hence the distribution of $X$! $P(X = (y,z) ) = P_Y(y) P_{Z|Y}(z|y)$.